# php artisan schedule:run, No scheduled commands are ready to run, not sure why?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why my cron job is not running. Even though if I manually run the custom command, it works. This is what the cronjob file looks like when I do `crontab -e`.

```
1 * * * * cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectName/app/console/Commands && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

when I run `php artisan schedule:run`

I get, No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Edit:

This is what my command class looks like:

```
class deletePics extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'picOfMonth:truncate';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Delete pics from old';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        PicOfMonth::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now())->each(function ($item) {
            $item->delete();
        });
    }
```

Also in my Kernel.php it looks like this:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        deletePics::class
    ];

 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('picOfMonth:truncate')->everyMinute();

    }
```

Comment: This says run the command at 1 minute past each hour.  You should have * * * * * for every minute

Comment: No scheduled commands are ready to run means that no entries in Kernel.php match the current time.

Comment: I've included the Kernel.php and Command class as well

Comment: Also, I had the cron job file starting as this before as well * * * * *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schedule commands should be in app\Console\Kernel.php and not Http\Kernel.php

Answer (score 0):

The cron schedule expression you are using, [executes the job every first minute after an hour](https://crontab.guru/#1_*_*_*_*). For example:

- 15:01
- 16:01
- 17:01

You are probably looking for an expression that runs every minute. If that's the case, you want [`* * * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*).

Comment: I actually had that before. I wonder if the problem is deeper, as when I do `php artisan schedule:list` there are no commands which come up on the list